# How do I get the Living Entity in this class? (Minecraft Modding 1.18.2)

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to make a food item (meth) that when you eat it it will stack the effect Amplifier each time. So I made this method to try and figure out if the player already has the effect and if so to make the effect amplifier 2 instead of the default 0. My big problem is when I try to use the method it of course requires a LivingEntity(the player) to use the method, what should I put in the methods parameters and how can I get the LivingEntity.

```
package net.tyrique.banhammermod.item.custom;

import net.minecraft.world.effect.MobEffectInstance;
import net.minecraft.world.entity.LivingEntity;
import net.minecraft.world.entity.player.Player;
import net.minecraft.world.food.FoodProperties;
import net.tyrique.banhammermod.effect.ModEffects;

public class MethFood {

    public static final FoodProperties METH = (new FoodProperties.Builder()).alwaysEat().nutrition(0).saturationMod(0F).effect(
            () -> new MobEffectInstance(ModEffects.METH_EFFECT.get(), 1500, isAlreadyHigh(**WHAT DO I PUT HERE!?**)), 1.0F).fast().build();



    private static int isAlreadyHigh(LivingEntity player) {
        int lvl = 0;
        if (player.hasEffect(ModEffects.METH_EFFECT.get())) {
            lvl = 2;
        }


        return lvl;
    }


}
```

I've already tried using some other techniques or possible methods to get the player but I don't know what else I can do. I'm sure the solution is simple.

**update(MobEffectInstance) Method Isolated:**

```
@Override
    public boolean update(MobEffectInstance p_19559_) {
        int newamp = p_19559_.getAmplifier() + 1;
        p_19559_ = new MobEffectInstance(p_19559_.getEffect(), p_19559_.getDuration(), newamp);
        return super.update(p_19559_);
    }
```

**ModMobEffectInstanceClass:**

```
public class ModMobEffectInstance extends MobEffectInstance {

    public ModMobEffectInstance(MobEffect effect, int duration, int amplifier) {
        super(effect, duration, amplifier);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(MobEffectInstance p_19559_) {
        int newamp = p_19559_.getAmplifier() + 1;
        p_19559_ = new ModMobEffectInstance(p_19559_.getEffect(), p_19559_.getDuration(), newamp);
        return super.update(p_19559_);
    }




}
```

**MethItemClass:**

```
public class MethFood {

    public static final FoodProperties METH = (new FoodProperties.Builder()).alwaysEat().nutrition(-1).saturationMod(0F).effect(
            () -> new ModMobEffectInstance(ModEffects.METH_EFFECT.get(), 1500, 0), 1.0F).fast().build();



}
```

Comment: It looks like you've already got the `LivingEntity` in your method's parameters. What seems to be the problem with your current approach?

Comment: If you look where it says "what do i put here". I need to input a LivingEntity for the method to work. I don't know how to get the living entity that is using the food.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a `LivingEntity` in that declaration because it is independent of any entities. It is declared before any entity even exists.
You need to find your entity when the effect is applied.

One way to do so is by subscribing to the `PotionAddedEvent` and putting your logic in the event handler.

First, you need to check if the same kind of effect is already on the LivingEntity. You can get the old effect from the `PotionEvent.PotionAddedEvent.getOldPotionEffect()` method. The method will return null if and only if the entity does not have the same type of effect yet.

Secondly, you need to check if the added effect is your effect in order to not interfere with other effects. You can get the added effect from the `PotionEvent.PotionAddedEvent.getPotionEffect()` method.

<strike>You probably will have to apply the effect a second time with the higher amplifier here because the event is not cancellable which is not super clean. Also make sure you don't cause an infinite loop of applying effects here.</strike>

Finally, you can update the added effect with a new MobEffectInstance with a higher amplifier by calling the `MobEffectInstance.update(MobEffectInstance)` method.

This is what the final event handler looks like:

```java
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onPotionAdded(PotionEvent.PotionAddedEvent event) {
        MobEffectInstance effect = event.getPotionEffect();
        if(event.getOldPotionEffect() == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (effect.getEffect().equals(ModEffects.METH_EFFECT.get())) {
            MobEffectInstance amplifiedEffect = new MobEffectInstance(effect.getEffect(), effect.getDuration(), effect.getAmplifier() + 1);         
            effect.update(amplifiedEffect);
        }
    }
```

---

<strike>Alternatively, you can probably create your own subclass of `MobEffectInstance` which overrides the `update(MobEffectInstance)` method. This is the method that is called whenever an effect is applied and the same effect already exists on that entity. Here you could create your own logic specialized for your item. You can then use your custom class in the declaration of your `METH` object. This is probably the cleaner but possibly more difficult way.</strike>

Comment: So I used the 2nd method you listed of creating a subclass and overriding the update(MobEffectInstance) method. But I can't get the method to work. I added the overridden update(MobEffectInstance) method I made into the original question near the bottom. I also can't find any info to backup that this is what this method actually does.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get the method to work"? Is the method being called at all? What happens? Have you done any debugging?
The update method looks good to me, assuming you only want to increase the amplifier once. Why are you doing "amplifier +1" in the constructor?
Did you use your ModMobEffectInstance in the declaration of your METH object?

I have the info about what this method does purely from the Minecraft source code.

Comment: I have used debug mode and overriding the update method does nothing, when I run the game in debug mode with any part of the "update" method "selected" the game never stops responding when it would supposedly do so. As to why I decided to do the "amplifier + 1" in the constructor, IDK I was just trying something there, it is not relevant to the problem. I did use the ModMobEffectInstance in the declaration of the METH object. I added the objects class too incase it helps, and also updated the code to what it is presently.

Comment: I would also like to know how I could "apply the effect a second time with the higher amplifier" in the interception of the "PotionAddedEvent"(i'm trying this too to see if I can get this to work instead). I just can't wrap my head around how I would do this in a subscriber event.

Comment: I took a look at it and it's my bad, the second method won't work because in the net.minecraft.world.entity.LivingEntity.addEatEffect(ItemStack, Level, LivingEntity) method the ModMobEffectInstance will be replaced by a MobEffectInstance. That is why your update method doesn't get called. I will edit my original answer soon to remove the second method and elaborate on the first.

Comment: I implemented the final event handler you provided but it is still never used, I even checked with debug mode. Is there anything I have to do with the event bus for it to work, or is there a certain class the event handler should be in?

Comment: The event handler needs to be registered to the MinecraftForge Event Bus. There are multiple ways of doing that as described in the [forge documentation](https://docs.minecraftforge.net/en/1.18.x/concepts/events/).